# How do I maximize power consumption of a CPU?

Tags: performance, cpu-usage

As a thought experiment, I want to maximize the power consumption of my CPU. (i.e. the least efficient CPU usage.)  Clearly it is a processor specific, but I expect there are some guidelines that would apply to all processors.

The simple solution might be to spawn a bunch of threads that run a simple loop that does:

```
static int count = 0;
while(true)
{
    ++count;
}
```

But these would not be necessarily using the most power consumptive instructions, or accessing memory, or many registers, or hitting caches, it would just be executing something every cycle.

Thoughts?

Comment: Not sure how this counts as a *thought experiment* when you're asking others to do the thinking for you...

Comment: I guess you can fork bomb and busy loop?

Answer (score 0):

1. The main consumer of power is the processor itself. The power saving features of the processor are based upon the ability of the processor to shut parts of itself down. Therefore, you want to keep all the processor busy all the time. Your busy loop is good but you want to keep it scaled to the number of cores available less 1. (The OS runs on that one generally, and you want to avoid task swapping because that will cause the processor to slow down and wait for memory operations.)
2. In your loop, do register to register vector operations. Memory operations take time and use less power than the processor.
3. If you can use hyper threading correctly, i.e. when there is more than one hardware thread per core, you can increase the utilization of the processor.

Forget about peripherals and memory. Their power consumption is small compared to the processor. And their use is slow, meaning the processor will likely enter a quiescent state (lower power) when waiting.

Maximizing the power consumed by a processor is essentially the same as optimizing the execution of a CPU bound application. Look at benchmarks designed by companies who want to make their processors look like the best thing since sliced bread. (Need I mention of whom I speak?)

Comment: Don't agree with "forget about memory".  If you do it right you should be able to keep the L1 and L2 caches busy without slowing down the CPU, and that's not a negligible number of gates you can get chattering.

Comment: You could be right. I think latencies for L1 are around 7 cycles, and for L2, around 15 cycles. Excellent CPI on current cores is maybe <.25 (meaning 4 inst per cycle). So if you can keep a low CPI, use vectorization, and exercise L1 & L2 (meaning no pipeline stalls), you've got an ideal situation.